# select2 search retrieve from ajax while retaining default options

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am trying to preload a set of data into a select2 dropdown, but I want to include this function whereby I can search for data thru ajax or local javascript array while retaining the options preloaded into the dropdown.

I am aware that we can load the select2 dropdown through ajax or javascript **separately** but I was wondering if we could combine these 2 functions together. I couldnt find any similar examples online and is wondering if anyone has done this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax.processResults` option to concat the preloaded options with the options returned from ajax. For example:

```
$('#yourSelect').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'your-api',
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        // Just for example, data is an array of options returned from ajax
        results: [{id: '', text: 'Choose an option'}, ...data];
      };
    }
  }
});
```